# RVM installation complaining of 'bison' not available in OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

On the installation notes of RVM, it is mentioned explicitly to have Xcode installed on OSX before installing RVM.

I had already downloaded it and installed it ages a go, so I did not have to do the installation again.

However when following the RVM installation, when I try to install a ruby version, e.g. `$ rvm install 1.9.2-head`, I get the following message:

> "Please ensure bison is installed before compiling from head."

And if I use homebrew to install it, I get the following:

```
$ brew install bison
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.h.rb:441: command not found: /usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path
Warning: Xcode is not installed! Builds may fail!
Error: No available formula for bison
```

Which is very strange for me, since I do have Xcode on my OSX box. Has anyone seem such a problem yet?

Comment: "I had already downloaded it and installed it ages a go, so I did not have to do the installation again." HOW long ago? They do update it periodically so you might be out of date. The current version of XCode is 3.2.5.

Comment: Hmmm. My version is the 3.1.2. It does not show, however, in the software update list. Do I really have to download the 3.5gb again? :(

Comment: No, you don't. You could choose to accept the errors you're getting if the download is too much. :-) Actually 3.5GB isn't that big a deal if you start it at night or in the background. There is a version on the Snow Leopard DVD but it's known to be buggy so the download is your best path to removing XCode problems from the equation.

Answer (score 5):

Command Line tools are not installed by default with Xcode 4.3.2. You need to start Xcode, go to Preferences, then click Downloads and install the command line tools. You should have bison after that. You can verify by running the command "which bison" in the terminal app.

[Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html)

Answer (score 0):

re-install Xcode from your installation DVD and then do a Software Update afterwards - it should upgrade Xcode to the latest version.

then try "which bison" .. it should be under /usr/bin as part of the Xcode installation